# Redis or threads in Python/Heroku?

Tags: python, multithreading, heroku, redis

I am new to this, so bear with me if I'm asking something completely stupid.

I am developing a basic web app and using Heroku+flask+python.

For the background tasks, Heroku recommends using a worker. I wonder if I could just create new threads for those background tasks? Or is there a reason why a worker+redis is a better solution?

Those background tasks are not critical, really.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main benefit to doing this in a separate worker is you'd be completely decoupling your app from your background tasks, so if one breaks it can't affect the other. That said, if you don't care about that, or need your background tasks more tightly coupled to your app for whatever reason, you can use [APScheduler](https://apscheduler.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) to have the background tasks run as separate threads without spinning up another worker. A simple example of that to run a background job every 10 seconds is as follows:

```
from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler
def some_job():
    print "successfully finished job!"
apsched = BackgroundScheduler()
apsched.start()
apsched.add_job(my_job, 'interval', seconds=10)
```

If you want tasks run asynchronously instead of on a schedule, you can use [RQ](http://python-rq.org/), which has great examples of how to use it on its homepage. RQ is backed by Redis, but you don't need to run it in a separate worker process, although you can if you like.

Comment: Thanks @eli. However, what if I want assynchronous execution on every request, rather than scheduling it?

Comment: @francisaugusto added info on how to do that.

Comment: Thanks @eli. But intead of RQ, could I simply start a thread with the background task, using `threads`?

Comment: Actually, is there a way to do it without Redis, simply using `threads`?